# Can I use arbitrary node modules from clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

Is it possible to use arbitrary node.js modules in a clojurescript project? If yes, how do I go about including them? If not, why not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can, there is nothing special about it:

```
(def fs (js/require "fs"))
(println (.readdirSync fs js/__dirname))
```

Be careful with the externs if you don't use optimizations none.

**Edit: Does leiningen play with the various js package managers?:**
Nope. Since the language does not have packages, it cannot know. You have to do js dependency management and lein deps too. There is a [lein-npm](https://github.com/bodil/lein-npm) and a [lein-bower](https://github.com/chlorinejs/lein-bower) to help with integrating these two package managers.

Comment: Nope. Since the language does not have packages, it cannot know. You have to do js dependency management and lein deps too. There is a [lein-npm](https://github.com/bodil/lein-npm) and a [lein-bower](https://github.com/chlorinejs/lein-bower) to help with integrating these two package managers.

Comment: Is it possible require a node module (i.e. "fs") into a cljs namespace such that you can access its methods directly? In this case, we would want to be able to say `(readdirSync js/__dirname)`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since late 2017. With shadow-cljs or Lumo now it's not problem to import npm modules in ClojureScript code anymore.

```
(ns app.main
  (:require ["dayjs"   :as dayjs]
            ["shortid" :as shortid]
            ["lodash"  :as lodash]
            ["lodash"  :refer [isString]]))
```

Read this topic for details: [Guide on how to use/import npm modules/packages in ClojureScript?](https://clojureverse.org/t/guide-on-how-to-use-import-npm-modules-packages-in-clojurescript/2298)

Answer (score 1):

Since ClojureScript 1.9.854, there's better support to declare npm modules as dependencies and to require them from your namespaces.

In order to declare it as a dependency, you need to use the `:npm-deps` compiler option (together with the `:install-deps` one, if you want `lein`/`boot`to automatically install it).

`:npm-deps` is a map from keyword to string, where the keyword is the name of the dependency you would use to install it using `npm` and the string is the version of the dependency.

An example of what you could add to your `project.clj` (if you use [lein-cljsbuild](https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild)), in order to use [left-pad:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/left-pad)

```
:cljsbuild {:builds [{:id "prod"
                    :source-paths ["src"]
                    :compiler {:main left-pad-demo.core
                               :output-to "package/index.js"
                               :target :nodejs
                               :output-dir "target"
                               :optimizations :simple
                               :install-deps true
                               :npm-deps {:left-pad "1.2.0"}
                               :pretty-print true}}]})
```

And then, from your namespace, you can require it like so:

```
(ns left-pad-demo.core
  (:require left-pad))
```

Or so:

```
(ns left-pad-demo.core
  (:require ["left-pad" :as lp]))
```

A full working namespace could look like:

```
(ns left-pad-demo.core
  (:require left-pad))

(defn -main [s length]
  (console.log (left-pad s length)))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

References:

- [Requiring Node.js modules from ClojureScript namespaces](https://anmonteiro.com/2017/03/requiring-node-js-modules-from-clojurescript-namespaces/)
- [ClojureScript is not an Island: Integrating Node Modules](https://clojurescript.org/news/2017-07-12-clojurescript-is-not-an-island-integrating-node-modules)